# `sample` triggers when complete. How to avoid?

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

```
let stream = PublishSubject<Int>()
let trigger = PublishSubject<Void>()

stream.sample(trigger).subscribeNext { value in print("value \(value)") }

stream.onNext(5)
trigger.onCompleted()
```

The above prints "value 5" to the console. I find that surprising since I never called onNext() on the trigger.

In my case the `trigger` represents a save button `rx_tap` and the `stream` represents valid input to be saved. My problem is that the stream is getting saved when the trigger completes (on destruction) even if it wasn't tapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `sample` does trigger `onCompleted` though
You can look it up in here:
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/sample.html

It works as expected in your case.

Normally, when you add `observers` into `DisposeBag`, it will be disposed when the bag is disposed.
For example: when ViewControllers or ViewModels are `deinit`ed...

So, the solution is just don't call `onCompleted` to dispose the `observers`

```
stream.sample(trigger)
      .subscribeNext { value in print("value \(value)") }
      .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

stream.onNext(5)
```